# How to Keybind XF86Forward in EMACS?

Tags: emacs

Hello it's currently binded to "Next Buffer"

But I don't know what XF86Forward or XF86Back is so I want to re-keybind it to F11 or F12. How do I go on about doing this in .emacs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To bind something to `XF86Back` `(global-set-key (kbd "<XF86Back>") 'something)`

To bind something to `F12` `(global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") 'something)`

To find out the name of the function a key is bound to, as well as the key's name, press `C-h k {key}`

Comment: The last part about C-h k was really helpful! I used the template for keybinding before, but it didn't work since I put it as " 'Next Buffer" rather than " 'next-buffer " which was the problem! After the command I was able to see.

Comment: @user2580104 There is also `C-h c {key}` it displays less information, but won't open an extra window.